# Do biologists believe in the existence of an intelligent creator who designed the architecture of life ?

Tags: evolution

I am referring to the biologists who does not support the theory of evolution or Darwinism .

Comment: Are you asking for the specific biologist or a general statement about biologist? because there are about as many biologists  who don't agree with evolution as there is medical doctors who don't agree with germ theory. which is to say a statistically insignificant number who are unable to scientifically defend their position. Basically there are ones who disagree because they are deeply religious but none that are religious becasue they disagree.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about biology but about the religious beliefs of biologists.

Answer (score 3):

As the question is phrased, there are almost none.

A [2009 Pew survey](http://www.pewforum.org/2009/11/05/scientists-and-belief/) concluded that

> 95% of Americans believe in some form of deity or higher power ... just over half of scientists (51%) believe in some form of deity or higher power; specifically, 33% of scientists say they believe in God, while 18% believe in a universal spirit or higher power.

That's American scientists in general; "biologists and medical" more specifically are in the same range. Americans in general tend to be far more religious than many other nationalities (95% of Americans vs. [less than 50% of British](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/british-people-atheist-no-religion-uk-christianity-islam-sikism-judaism-jewish-muslims-a7928896.html), [60% of Germans](https://www.deutschland.de/en/topic/life/religious-faith-in-germany%3Amany-germans-are-leaving-the-church), [65% of Canadians](https://www.crop.ca/en/blog/2017/169/)) and it's likely that scientists from other countries are proportionately less likely to believe in a God. I don't have numbers for those but let's say 60% of the American number, or roughly 20%.

So there is a significant minority of scientists who are religious, but probably 70-80% of biologists worldwide do not believe in God.

Does that mean that 20-30% of biologists reject evolution based on their religious beliefs? Not at all. The idea that evolution conflicts with religious beliefs is a very niche view, mainly held by small (but very noisy) American religious groups. For example, the Pope has stated that there is [no conflict between Catholicism and evolution](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/pope-francis-declares-evolution-and-big-bang-theory-are-right-and-god-isnt-a-magician-with-a-magic-9822514.html). [Francis Collins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Collins), the director of the NIH, is famously religious and also argues that there is no conflict between religion and evolution.

So there's no reason to believe that religious scientists should reject evolution, and in fact they don't. Surveys show that around [97% of scientists](http://www.people-press.org/2009/07/09/section-5-evolution-climate-change-and-other-issues/) understand that evolution is real. That survey says that "*87% say evolution is due to natural processes, such as natural selection*", which leaves 13% as open to the idea that it's guided. That survey doesn't break down different fields, but other surveys and general experience says that few of the 13% are biologists.

The number of biologists who reject evolution based on their religion is tiny.

As a side note, please be aware that "Darwinism" is not a real thing; it's made-up phrase used by people who know little or nothing about biology, who are unaware that Darwin's arguments have been irrelevant to our understand of of modern evolution for close to 100 years, and that modern evolutionary theory has many branches that supplant and extend classical natural selection.

Comment: But the question is so clearly off-topic that you are doing a disservice to the list by feeding this troll.

Comment: @user1136 IMO, the question is completely and obviously off-topic. Asking about the sociology of religious believes has nothing to do with biology even when the population of interest is "biologists". This question is as off-topic as it gets!